# Balancing dataset and normalizing features: what comes first?

Tags: normalization, unbalanced-classes, data-preprocessing

I have a unbalanced data set, that for the purpose of training I wish to balance. What is a better practice? First balancing the train data and then feature scaling/normalizing or using the mean and standard deviation of the skewed set?

Thanks for your help! =)

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about a predictive model? I will assume yes. Also assume you are talking about balancing the target variable for rare class classification tasks. My thought would be to standardize (normalizing is typically using the min and max values not mean and standard deviation) the data first and then over-sample if that is what you are thinking in terms of balancing. I say this because you will want to use that same mean/std dev of the original set when you standardize new data so that it mirrors the training set that was used. The suggestion above not to balance is not true, it really depends on how rare the rare class is and the technique. Often, machine learning algorithms work better with closer to balance data (either explicitly or through use of weights).

Comment: "The suggestion above not to balance is not true, it really depends on how rare the rare class is and the technique. Often, machine learning algorithms work better with closer to balance data (either explicitly or through use of weights)." — Why do you say so? I don't see why a model would be improved by distorting the training data in this way. Weighting of data points makes sense if you know some points are more important or more informative than others, but not merely as an attempt to compensate for imbalanced data.

Comment: This is a pretty well known issue and you can find lots of things in Google. For example, a couple quick links of the practical variety. 

https://svds.com/learning-imbalanced-classes/

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/practical-guide-deal-imbalanced-classification-problems/

Empirically, we find better performance often (read: not always - there is no free lunch) in closer to balanced classes. This doesnt mean 50/50 when the rare class is very rare - that excludes too much information from the majority class. It means oversampling (for example) to achieve say 1% rare class

Comment: ...compared to 0.0001%! Some of the issues are algorithmic as touched on by the links, some are based on constraints in hardware - if the majority class is exceptionally rare, there is no need to carry the computational burden of 10,000 negative cases for each positive one.

Comment: As you point out, weighting is another way to balance the data set and it does exactly as you say - which data points are more important than others. In the case of a rare class, these are often the more important ones (e.g. fraud, cancer, response to a marketing direct mail....)

Comment: So, it is not correct to say  it is unwise to balance, because there are lots of real world cases (almost all I deal with actually) where it is very wise. HTH

Comment: B_Miner, thank you for your answer! You made all the right assumptions ;) (I just tried to keep my question simple and short, but with that missed some info maybe..)
And what you say about balancing, I read a lot about this too and agree with you. Here is a blog of someone trying to prove the opposite, http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/02/does-balancing-classes-improve-classifier-performance/ He wrote some considerations on when to and when not to balance.

Comment: @B_Miner From your links, I can't see how these things could improve a classifier's performance except when you're using a metric under which one kind of error (false positive vs. false negative) is more important than the other. And when that's case, that suffices to justify weighting even when the data is balanced. So imbalance seems a bit of a red herring.

Comment: Not sure your point. Accuracy is the canonical example where this comes into play because a classifier can be 99.9% right by always predicting the majority class (say in fraud / network intrusion cases etc) but be totally worthless. In theory, one could use weights to accomplish the same thing as explicitly balancing a data set - often oversampling the rare class is what is meant by this. There are many times though where weighting does not work or does not work as well. Empirically, this is seen in practice.

Comment: There are algorithms that dont allow weights, cases where the majority class is so large that one has to oversample the rare class to run an algorithm (think web scale data as an extreme example) because not doing so is infeasible / intractable. Sometimes where weighting is possible it works better than oversampling....some times not. No free lunch in predictive modeling right. So, sorry but your blanked statement that you should never balance a training set is incorrect.

Comment: @B_Minder "Not sure your point." — My point is that an asymmetric loss function is necessary and sufficient to justify reweighting (or, since you say this isn't always possible, oversampling or undersampling). If you're using a symmetric measure, like accuracy, then you're not going to benefit from such things no matter how imbalanced the data is to start with.

Comment: Over/under sampling is a symptom of not understanding limits of classification and improper accuracy scoring rules.  See http://fharrell.com/post/classification

Answer (score -2):

> I have a unbalanced data set, that for the purpose of training I wish to balance.

By which you mean, throw out or duplicate observations? This is unwise. It will only make your model worse.

So, just normalize and forget about balancing.

Comment: Over- and under-sampling are known to improve machine learning models in many classification tasks. See e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06048.pdf

Comment: @Denwid See my comments on the other answer: "an asymmetric loss function is necessary and sufficient to justify reweighting". I admit that duplicating or removing observations is better than nothing when your model doesn't admit weighting… but if you have an asymmetric loss function, you should probably be using a model that admits weighting.